# How to capture data within a given time frame based on an hour basis?

Tags: python, pandas, python-datetime

I'm still learning Python and sometimes my coding is not very efficient. I'm looking for a more efficient way to adequately group data entry by "hourly basis". This is to measure production every hour not an average of hourly production (Yes, I know this would be much much simple. To give an example if I did something 32 times within 4:30-5:30 and between 5:30-6:30 I did 58 and that was it for the day these two time frames would not be an average of hourly production but would stay static which is what I need. The time frames in which it must fit within are `(4:30-5:30, 5:30-6:30, 6:30-7:30, 7:30-8:30, 8:30-9:30, 9:30-10:30, 11:00-12:00, 12:00-1:00, 1:00-2:00, 2:00-3:00, 3:00-4:00, 4:00-5:00, 5:00-6:00, 6:00-7:00, 7:30-8:30, 8:30-9:30, 9:30-10:30, 10:30-11:30, 11:30-12:30, 12:30-1:30)`. I already have GUI for data entry into excel. I have two columns labeled as ***`"Time" and "Date"`**, **Time** is where I manipulated hour and minute.

```
a_list = [2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11]
b_list = [11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19]
c_list = [19,20,21,22,23,0]
date = dt.datetime.now()
#hm =  float(date.strftime('%H.%M'))
#hour = float(date.strftime('%H'))
hour = float(5) #testing 
hm =  float(5.30) #testing
for i in a_list:
    if hour in a_list:
        if hour < 5:
            hour = 5
            a ="{:.2f}".format(hour) 
            print(f'Test 1:{a}')
            break
        if hour+.5 >= 5.5 and hour <10:
            if hm >= hour +.3:
                a ="{:.2f}".format(hour+1)
                print(f'Test 2: {a}')
            else: 
                a ="{:.2f}".format(hour) 
                print(f'Test 3: {a}')
        if hour >= 10: 
            hour = 10
            a ="{:.2f}".format(hour)
            print(f'Test 4: {a}')
    break
```

I have not yet added any code for the other list. I'm looking for better ideas then what I have here. I thought about date ranges but might run into complications. Here is a reference image of two of the columns:

[image]

[image]

Comment: I would recomment using a proper timestamp value in your excel source data and also use [datetime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) in your python code, instead of reimplementing time calculations. Except when this is your goal (e.g. for education purposes).

Comment: @blurryroots I may have not been able to wrap my head around it but I did use date time before this and I could not group the data the way I needed. I probably just do not know the method of doing so but for example 2022-01-06 4:30:00 and 2022-01-06 4:45:00 would need to be grouped together under 4:30-5:30. I am trying to avoid 1000 if statements like the code above and something that has less "steps". There are other columns in this table not just the two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the [datetime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) module, it is certainly possible to avoid cumbersome if-else salads.
To create time windows and register activity within these windows, let's consider the following:

```py
import datetime

def calculate_slot(point_in_time, base, windows, length = datetime.timedelta(hours = 1)):
    '''Calculates the slot index of a given time relative to a base time and a list of time windows with a certain length.'''
    slot = -1
    # check if the time is further in the future than the end of the day.
    if (base + windows[-1] + length) <= point_in_time:
        return slot
    # increase the slot index, as long as the time is still bigger than the window time.
    while (slot+1) < len(windows) and (base + windows[slot+1]) < point_in_time:
        slot += 1

    return slot

def register_activity(activity_log, base, windows, point_in_time):
    '''Stores an entry in a slot depending on the point in time given.'''
    # in which window does the given time fit?
    slot = calculate_slot(point_in_time, base, windows)
    # only add if slot is valid.
    if -1 < slot:
        activity_log[slot].append(point_in_time)

def main():
    # when does the first time window start?
    base = datetime.datetime(2021, 1, 6)
    # what are the starting points of each window?
    windows = [
        datetime.timedelta(hours = 4, minutes = 30),
        datetime.timedelta(hours = 5, minutes = 30),
        datetime.timedelta(hours = 6, minutes = 30),
        datetime.timedelta(hours = 7, minutes = 30),
        datetime.timedelta(hours = 8, minutes = 30),
        datetime.timedelta(hours = 9, minutes = 30),
        datetime.timedelta(hours = 11, minutes = 00),
        datetime.timedelta(hours = 12, minutes = 00),
        datetime.timedelta(hours = 13, minutes = 00),
        datetime.timedelta(hours = 14, minutes = 00),
        datetime.timedelta(hours = 15, minutes = 00),
        datetime.timedelta(hours = 16, minutes = 00),
        datetime.timedelta(hours = 17, minutes = 00),
        datetime.timedelta(hours = 18, minutes = 00),
        datetime.timedelta(hours = 19, minutes = 30),
        datetime.timedelta(hours = 20, minutes = 30),
        datetime.timedelta(hours = 21, minutes = 30),
        datetime.timedelta(hours = 22, minutes = 30),
        datetime.timedelta(hours = 23, minutes = 30),
        datetime.timedelta(hours = 24, minutes = 30),
    ]

    # prepare the activity log with enought slots.
    activity_log = []
    for _ in range(0, len(windows)):
        activity_log.append([])

    # point in time to test against.
    search_time0 = datetime.datetime(2021, 1, 6, 8, 15)
    search_time1 = datetime.datetime(2021, 1, 6, 23, 42)
    search_time2 = datetime.datetime(2021, 1, 7, 1, 11)

    # register activity on specific times.
    register_activity(activity_log, base, windows, search_time0)
    register_activity(activity_log, base, windows, search_time1)
    register_activity(activity_log, base, windows, search_time2)

    # show activity log.
    print(activity_log)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The concept is, to define a base time (the day of consideration) and create a list of starting times for each window. Using [timedelta](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects) a window is defined by the time distance relative to the start time.

To figure out, in which window / slot an activity at a certain time belongs, the windows are checked from earliest to latest.

For the activity log, a list of lists (with the number of inner lists equal to the number of windows / slots) is used. To register an activity, the slot of a given time is calculated and if a slot has been found, the time is inserted into the inner list.

Hope this serves as a source of inspiration for your application.

Comment: Thanks, I was going to use a method similar to this early on but thought I'd try something different and came up with that my gibberish I have above. Thought I'd check the community for their input and problems I might run into.

Comment: @Iamar249 We're all on a journey. Don't feel bad about starting out with *'gibbersih'* and don' take things personally. Hope you enjoy learning from the answer as much as I do in giving it. If one can spare the time and resources, it's very valuable to try things on your own (regardless of the outcome) and then check back with the tribe on how to improve, rather than just go along with the narrative - or worse - let somebody else do all the work for you in the frist place. You did good.